# Can't set a RCtrl HotKey Combination with Autohotkey?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

I'm trying to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to send <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> + <kbd>LAlt</kbd> hotkey, but it doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
^g::
Send, {RCtrlDown}{Alt}{RCtrlUp}
return
```

I've also tried:

- `Send, {RCtrlDown}{LAlt}{RCtrlUp}`
- `Send, {RCtrlDown}{LAltDown}{RCtrlUp}`
- `Send, {RCtrlDown}{LAltDown}{RCtrlUp}{LAltUp}`

with no success.

I'm on Windows 10 Pro. I have another program which listens for the <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> + <kbd>LAlt</kbd> hotkey; I'm not sure if that's interfering with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm `{RControl up}` or `{RCtrl up}` or `{LAlt up}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me :

```
^g::
Send, {RCtrl Down}{Alt}{RCtrl Up}
return
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I said lol

Comment: @Gantendo: I didn't see your comment.

Comment: But why does it work

Comment: @RohitGupta OP is missing a space between the name of the key and the word up

Comment: @Gantendo, I didn't have a problem understanding it.  But Harrymc should know better.  It was prompt to him to improve his code-only answer.  I refrained from flagging it for deletion in review because it has value.  See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)